# Hi everyone , I am new to jQuery and I was asked this question but I don't know how to do it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ron recently started his carrier in developing web applications.  As a part of his first project, he is assigned to create a web page using jQuery library.  He created the web page and now he wants to check whether jQuery is loaded on his web page or not.  For this, he wants to display a message “jQuery is loaded!!!” on his web page when the page is loaded.  Help Ron to perform the task.

Does anyone know how to write a code to check if jQuery is loaded or not ?
[enter image description here][1]

This is the code of html .I want to know the jQuery code for this .Thanks in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E5mS.png

Comment: Please may you read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Add a hidden div, then show it in doc.ready (using jquery).  Next iteration: add the div with jquery

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

$('#msg').text('jQuery is loaded!!!');